# Printing on the same line different Permuations of a value

Tags: python-3.x

Hey guys so here is my question. I have written code that sums two prime numbers and prints the values less than or equal to 100 and even. How do I write it so that every combination of the number prints on the same line

like so

100 =  3 + 97 = 11 + 89

```
def isPrime(n):
    limit = int(n ** 0.5) +1
    for divisor in range (2, limit):
        if (n % divisor == 0):
            return False
    return True

def main():
    a = 0
    b = 0
    for n in range (4, 101):
        if (n % 2 == 0):
            for a in range (1, n + 1):
                if isPrime(a):
                    for b in range (1, n + 1):
                        if isPrime(b):
                            if n == (a + b):
                                print ( n, "=", a, "+", b)

main()
```

any ideas?

I don't know too much about strings yet, but I was thinking we could set the string as n == a + b and some how repeat on the same line where n == n print the a + b statement or idk haha

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to accumulate a and b pairs in some collection, then print a line containing all the pairs. Here's an example with some comments explaining whats going on and general Python tips:

```
def main():
    for n in range (4, 101, 2): # range() can have third argument -> step
        accumulator = []
        for a in filter(isPrime, range(1, n + 1)): # filter() is useful if you want to skip some values
            for b in filter(isPrime, range (1, n + 1)):
                if n == (a + b):
                    accumulator.append((a,b)) # We accumulate instead of printing
        str_accumulator = ["{} + {}".format(i[0], i[1]) for i in accumulator]
        joined_accumulator = " = ".join(str_accumulator)
        print("{} = {}".format(n, joined_accumulator))
```

Now, some explanation:

range(4, 101, 2) - as said in comment, it has an optional third argument. Some examples and explanations on how to use range in [documentation](http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/functions.html#range).

filter() - Very useful generic iterator constructor. You pass a function that returns True/False, a collection, and you receive an iterator that spits out only those elements from the collection that are accepted by the function. See [documentation](http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/functions.html#filter).

str.format - For me, format is the best way to paste values into strings. It has PLENTY options and is very versatile. You should read the whole [documentation here](http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/string.html#formatstrings).

str.join - When you have a collection of string, and you want to make one string of them, join is what you want. It's much faster than str + str operation, and also you don't have to care if there is one or many elements in the collection. See [documentation](http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/stdtypes.html#str.join).